# I don't know how to use Beej's programm from his Guide

Tags: c++, network-programming

1I'm reading Beej's programming network guide. I read his code and did an important change to check ipv6 but it's not working right. Can't get an ip Address. How to use this on a Linux system? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWEME.png

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int status;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: showip hostname\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

    for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        char *ipver;

        // get the pointer to the address itself,
        // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        } else if (p->ai_family==AF_INET6) { // IPv6
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }

        // convert the IP to a string and print it:
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
        printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res); // free the linked list

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: You sure this is C++ and not C?

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of code running.  In any case, your output reveals you have an argument parsing problem, not an issue with invoking getaddrinfo.

Comment: Does it make any sense in this context?

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious:

You check to make sure `argc` is 2 to validate you have at least one argument.  Makes sense

```
if (argc != 2) {
```

But then later:

```
if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[2], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
```

You reference `argv[2]`, which is undefined when the only valid indicies in `argv` are `0` and `1`.

Pretty sure you meant to use `argv[1]` as follows:

```
if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
```

Also, this is a bug:

```
    // convert the IP to a string and print it:
    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
    printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
```

Nothing wrong with those statements, but when `p->ai_family` is neither `AF_INET` nor `AF_INET6`, then those statements get executed anyway.  `addr` and `ipver` are undefined.  Hence, undefined behavior.  And yes, on Linux, there's plenty of address types that are not IP based.

You are welcome to reference my [ResolveHostname function on Github](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/networkutils/resolvehostname.cpp).

Comment: Oh, thx. Yes, I did a typo, but in Original I tried to run like you said. The result is same.

Comment: How many arguments does your program take?  What you posted as code is clearly bugged. But the picture you posted implies you have a 3 arguments version.

Comment: I'm not sure about 3 arguments. Does it count "./programName" like an argument when I run the program from CLI?

Comment: Comment corrected.  `"./programName"` is always `argv[0]`.  The first real argument to the program on the command line is `argv[1]`.  So if I invoke `./foo abc` then  `argc` is 2 and argv[1] is `"abc"`  Make sense?